# Equivalence of quantum circuits

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, logical-gates

I have these 2 quantum circuits:

[image]

Are they equivalent?I think they are but I cannot understand how this could be possible.Lets assume that the initial condition of the first circuit is:]

Lets assume that gate A transforms any qubit
$
\begin{pmatrix}
f\\ 
e 
\end{pmatrix}
$
into:
$
\begin{pmatrix}
f'\\ 
e' 
\end{pmatrix}
$
and gate B transforms any 2 qubit system from:
$
\begin{pmatrix}
gi\\ 
gj\\ 
hi\\ 
hj
\end{pmatrix}
$
into:
$
\begin{pmatrix}
gi\\ 
gj\\ 
hi''\\ 
hj''
\end{pmatrix}
$

Lets take the first system.From a initial condition of:

$
\begin{pmatrix}
ac\\ 
ad\\ 
bc\\ 
bd
\end{pmatrix}
$
after gate A it becomes:
$
\begin{pmatrix}
a'c\\ 
a'd\\ 
b'c\\ 
b'd
\end{pmatrix}
$
and after controlled gate B it becomes:
$
\begin{pmatrix}
a'c\\ 
a'd\\ 
b'c''\\ 
b'd''
\end{pmatrix}
$
Now lets take the second system.From a initial condition of:
$
\begin{pmatrix}
ac\\ 
ad\\ 
bc\\ 
bd
\end{pmatrix}
$
after gate B it becomes:

$
\begin{pmatrix}
ac\\ 
ad\\ 
bc''\\ 
bd''
\end{pmatrix}
$
and after gate A it becomes:
$
\begin{pmatrix}
a'c\\ 
a'd\\ 
b'c''\\ 
b'd''
\end{pmatrix}
$
so the 2 are equivalent?But this cannot be correct , intuitively it is not correct.Where am I wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your notation is leading you astray. In your first way of writing the circuit, you have the gate $B$ achieving the change in amplitudes $b'c\rightarrow b'c''$ while in the second you have $bc\rightarrow bc''$ assuming that those two $c''$ should be the same. There is no reason that they should be.

To illustrate this more concretely, consider $A$ and $B$ both being the not gate, and both qubits start in $|0\rangle$. In the first case, you get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
while in the second case, you get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The initial conditions for the controlled-B gate are different between the two cases, so give different outputs.

Comment: But the gate is the same so they should be the same.Well obviously the initial condition is the same and the gates are the same.

Comment: but the initial conditions are *not* the same. $b'c$ and $bc$ are different initial conditions.

Comment: u mean before the gate B is acted on the system?True but I dont see why it would make such a big difference.

Comment: It makes *all* the difference.

Answer (score 1):

The circuits are not equivalent in general. As an example, take $A = B = X$. The unitary matrices representing the circuits are different:

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator

qc1 = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc1.x(0)
qc1.cx(0, 1)
display(qc1.draw())
display(Operator(qc1).draw('latex'))


qc2 = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc2.cx(0, 1)
qc2.x(0)
display(qc2.draw())
display(Operator(qc2).draw('latex'))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi.Can you spot my mistake in the calculations?

Answer (score 1):

No, these two circuits won't be equivalent in general.

Reasoning with states might not be the easiest way to understand it, I found expressing $A$ and $B$ in terms of matrices more clear.

Consider $A = \begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\ a_{21}&a_{22}\end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix}b_{11}&b_{12}\\ b_{21}&b_{22}\end{pmatrix}$.

The $A$ gate applied to the first qubit correspond to the operator (written in block matrix notation):

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}I_2 & a_{12}I_2 \\
a_{21}I_2& a_{22}I_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $I_2$ is the $2\times2$ identity matrix.

The controlled-$B$ gate has matrix representation:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
I_2 & 0 \\
0& B
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Hence, the first circuit seen overall as a matrix is:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}I_2 & a_{12}I_2 \\
a_{21}B& a_{22}B
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Whereas the second circuit is:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}I_2 & a_{12}B \\
a_{21}I_2& a_{22}B
\end{pmatrix}
$$

As a result, the circuits can only be equivalent if $a_{21}I_2 = a_{21}B$ and $a_{12}I_2 = a_{12}B$.

This condition is never met unless $a_{21} = a_{12} = 0$ i.e. the matrix $A$ is diagonal (or in the trivial case $B=I_2$).

You can check that taking $A=B=X$ doesn't give you an equivalence between the circuit, but taking $A=Z$ and $B=X$ does as $Z$ is a diagonal matrix.